# How to use ts-transformer-keys in nextjs project?

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, typescript-typings

I want to get keys from interface as string array so that I can iterate over them.Over stackoverflow I found I need to use a library 'ts-transformer-keys'.
Since in nextjs project we have both webpack and typescript so  I have added configurations for webpack and tsconfig.json mentioned for ttypescript and webpack mentioned in the below link.

https://github.com/iqraabdulrauf/ts-transformer-keys/blob/master/README.md

The problem is project is not getting compiled with both loaders i.s 'ts-loader' and 'awesome-typescript-loader'.It does not pickup the _document.tsx files under pages folder present in nextjs project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch [ts-patch](https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch) , [ts-transformer-keys](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys)

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "plugins": [
      { "transform": "ts-transformer-keys/transformer" }
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

**UPD**
if upper not works, set the `next.config.js`:

```
const keysTransformer = require('ts-transformer-keys/transformer').default;
const enumerateTransformer = require('ts-transformer-enumerate/transformer').default;
const isTransformer = require('typescript-is/lib/transform-inline/transformer').default;

const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants');
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {

    const config = {
        webpack: (config, options) => {
            config.module.rules.push({
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader', // or 'next-babel-loader'
                options: {
                    // make sure not to set `transpileOnly: true` here, otherwise it will not work
                    getCustomTransformers: program => ({
                        before: [
                            keysTransformer(program),
                            enumerateTransformer(program),
                            isTransformer(program)
                        ]
                    })
                }
            });

            return config
        },
    };
    if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER) {
         // ...
    }

    return Object.assign (config, {
        // constants to process.env.
    });
};
```

Install `ts-loader` if not installed. Also you can use `next-babel-loader`.